# Is there any convention for where to store Enums in an ASP.Net WebAPI application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, enums

I would like to create an Enum in my WebAPI application but I have not seen this done before. Is there any convention for how these are named, defined and stored in ASP.NET applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing special about `Enum` in *WebAPI*. You can declare an `Enum` wherever you want. Although of course, it makes sense to have it defined inside the *Data Access* project along with *Entities*, *Repositories* etc.

There's also no convention about naming. Some people like to append "Enum" at the end, others don't.

```
public enum ColorOptions { ... }
```

or

```
public enum ColorOptionsEnum { ... }
```

If you have an entity *Car* and you want it to have a *ColorOptions* `Enum` property, it makes sense to store the two alongside:

```
public class Car
{
    public ColorOptions AvailableColorOptions { set; get; }
}

[Flags]
public enum ColorOptions
{
    Black,
    Red,
    Blue,
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the .NET Framework Design Guidelines do dictate naming conventions for enums. While some people do like to add "Enum" to the names of enums, it's not recommended:

> Names of enumeration types (also called enums) in general should follow the standard type-naming rules (PascalCasing, etc.). However, there are additional guidelines that apply specifically to enums.
>
> - √ DO use a singular type name for an enumeration unless its values are bit fields.
> - √ DO use a plural type name for an enumeration with bit fields as values, also called flags enum.
> - X DO NOT use an "Enum" suffix in enum type names.
> - X DO NOT use "Flag" or “Flags" suffixes in enum type names.
> - X DO NOT use a prefix on enumeration value names (e.g., "ad" for ADO enums, "rtf" for rich text enums, etc.).

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229040%28v=vs.110%29.aspx